# ANTLR Lexer rules - enter a pushMode based on what is in the beginning of line

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to enter a mode in lexer based on how the line of text begins? Here's the source thing I am parsing:

```
1. Top Level item 
  1. Second level item #1
  2. Second level item #2
```

So, if line starts with a digit followed by a period, I would like it to enter into a TOP_LEVEL mode. If however it starts with two spaces, then digit followed by a period, then I'd like it to sink into SECOND_LEVEL mode:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;

TOP_LEVEL_ANCHOR: DIGIT+ PERIOD SPACE? ->pushMode(TOP_LEVEL);
SECOND_LEVEL_ANCHOR: SPACE SPACE DIGIT+ PERIOD SPACE ->pushMode(SECOND_LEVEL);
```

It however always catches the TOP_LEVEL_ANCHOR. Am I messing with whitespace stuff somehow? I do not have anything like -> skip or hidden channel in the lexer. The rest of it:

```
 PERIOD: '.';
 SPACE: ' ';
 NL: '\r'? '\n';
 NON_QUOTED_STRING: [^a-zA-Z0-9] ~('\n' | '\r' | ',' )* ;
 DOUBLE_QUOTED_STRING: '"' ~('\\'|'"')* '"' ;
```

The source document is going to have a few more flavours differentiated by a pattern the line starts with, so wanted to make sure I am digging into the right direction. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the given input, modes are not likely the right feature to use.  Modes are typically used to contextually distinguish between otherwise ambiguous character sequences -- you are aware that when you enter a mode, the lexer rules in all other modes, including the default mode, are effectively invisible, right?

Use the lexer to recognize discrete character sequences as tokens.  Use the parser to recognize syntactical relations between tokens.  Use a walker to analyze semantic relations.

For example, you could allow the lexer to ignore all whitespace, let the parser recognize list elements (independent of level), and when walking, on entry to each list element context, reference the input stream to count leading whitespace.

Comment: I thought the less work I do in the walker the better, thought to use it only to create domain models filled with data from parser. The most I thought to do in walker was to sanitise some things by trimming blanks from strings etc.

Thanks for the tip, going to consider it and evaluate.

Comment: Walkers are inherently fast, so it is easy to use many with each dedicated to a particular task (answering a specific semantic question).  There is also XPath that allows you to probe for specific nodes (test semantic relations) in the parsed tree.  If the answer helped, please accept.